# Show text only if load the "font-family"

Tags: html, css, fonts

I would like to know if it is possible for a text to only appear if the special "font-family" applied in that text has been loaded.

I would like it if you do not load the font does not get to show the text.

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Moonogram;
    src: local(Moonogram),
         url('fonts/Moonogram.ttf') format("truetype");
}

.specialtext{
    font-family: 'Moonogram';
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="specialtext">This text</p>
```

Thank you for beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that I have understood your question correctly, you want to dynamically hide/show a specific piece of text (but not all)... From my research it is not possible to detect what fonts are used. There are work arounds that compares the height sizes of the text according to different fonts and then suggests a font that it **could** be using. However, I perceive this to be a hack and is far from accurate.

I can suggest to you to use a class based system. So your font would be assigned to a class:

```
.specialFont {   
  font-family: "specialFont";
}
```

The text should have a `display:none;` css attribute on its main class.

Then your special text could have this special class...

```
<p class="specialtext specialFont">This text</p>
```

Then you could detect if it has the special font class via jQuery...

```
if ($('.specialtext').hasClass("specialFont")) {
  $(this).show();
}
```

In fact, you could shorten this to:

```
$('.specialtext.specialFont').show();
```